# SFDC and SFMC Integration

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to integrate SFDC and SFMC. I am following the directions that Salesforce provided but I'm stuck on the subscriber key. How do you complete a Subscriber Key Migration?

Thanks,
Kathleen

Answer (score 1):

A susbcriberkey migration is used to change existing subscriber keys. You need to open a ticket with Salesforce Support to do this